# Match all JavaScript blocks

Tags: c#, regex

I ma trying to match all JavaScript blocks in a html file.

Currently I am using:

```
 content = Regex.Replace(content, "<script.*type=\"text/javascript.*</script>", String.Empty);

 content = Regex.Replace(content, @"<script\s*.*type=\'text/javascript\s*.*\s*</script>", String.Empty);
```

But, for example, I can't match this string:

```
<script src="http://mediamond.js.ad.dotandad.com/MediamondAds.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" id=
"mediamondBaseJS"></script>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I have tried your suggestion, it is a step nearer to the solution, but now it is too greedy (or maybe the `</script>` at the start of the line poses some problem?)

I am using:

```
Regex.Match(content, @"<script[\s\S]*?type='text/javascript[\s\S]*?</script>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
```

I have also tried with the start-of-line ^

but the match now is too long (the first `</script>` is ignored!):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var mediamondAd=new MediamondAds();
mediamondAd.setTagPfx("br_fol_for_mi");
</script>
<!-- MEDIAMOND END -->

<div align="center" style="padding-top: 10px;"><script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[
    OA_show(26);  
// ]]> --></script>
```

Comment: Why not using an html parser? See: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot character won't match line breaks. Your html has a newline between the `language` attribute and the closing script tag. Consider using this instead:

```
<script[\s\S]*?type=\"text\/javascript[\s\S]*?</script>

\s = whitespaces (including line breaks)
\S = non-spaces
? = non-greedy so it stops looking when it gets the first type attribute / first closing </script> tag
```